# Stop VS Code from adding 'as' or alias in destructured assignment when renaming in JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I rename a variable in JavaScript or TypeScript, VS Code sometimes adds aliases in destructured assignments:

```
const { renamedProp: prop } = arg; // After rename
```

or it adds `as` in imports:

```
import { Foo as renamedFoo } from "./file"; // After rename
```

Why does VS Code do this and how can I disable this behavior? For example, if I rename `prop` in interface `Foo` for the following code:

```
export interface Foo {
    prop: string;
}

function bar(arg: Foo) {
    const { prop } = arg;
    return prop;
}
```

VS Code changes the code to:

```
export interface Foo {
    renamedProp: string;
}

function bar(arg: Foo) {
    const { renamedProp: prop } = arg;
    return prop;
}
```

I want it to be:

```
export interface Foo {
    renamedProp: string;
}

function bar(arg: Foo) {
    const { renamedProp } = arg;
    return renamedProp;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

By default, VS Code attempts to make renames safe. This means preserving the existing interfaces of types. In cases like the following example,

```
export interface Foo {
    prop: string; 
}

function bar(arg: Foo) {
    const { prop } = arg; 
    return { prop };
}
```

If we rename `prop` without using aliases, the implicitly returned type of `bar` would change. And maybe this type was used to satisfy another interface that expects a property called `prop`. In this case, introducing an alias on rename preserves the existing type interfaces whichs ensures that the code continues to compile and work as expected

**To disabled this behavior**, just set:

```
"javascript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false,
"typescript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false,
```

These settings are only supported when using TypeScript 3.4+ in your workspace (this is the default in VS Code 1.33+)

Comment: The setting 'typescript.preferences.renameShorthandProperties' has been deprecated in favor of 'typescript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames'. So, now you should use the following settings in `Preferences:Configure Language Specific Settings` ->
`"typescript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false, "javascript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false`